# Windows, Python27 ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have read many of the questions and answers regarding "IncompleteRead" most, if not all, of them end up with a recommendation to uninstall and reinstall pip, or upgrade pip, or uninstall and reinstall the package you are trying to install.

I am not able to even upgrade pip or uninstall it.
Here is the traceback:

```
c:\Python27>python.exe -m pip install -U pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `pip install requests -U`.

Comment: Thank you @MariosNikolaou this crashes with the same error

Comment: You are on windows, right?

Comment: Yes, on Windows..

Comment: I think if you install Anaconda it will be much easier.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I took you up on your recommendation, installed Anaconda and now have a new error - on import numpy --> from . import _distributor_init --> from . import _mklinit Import Error: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. 
I'm starting to think I should uninstall and reinstall python entirely

Comment: yes, do clean uninstall of python and install Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and remove requests module first dist-packages

```
rm -rf python2.7/dist-packages/requests*
```

pip module need requests module to download packages from Python Package Index.

Hope this might help

Comment: Can you first delete the request module and reinstall it and then try upgrade pip and see if that works?

Comment: I can delete by deleting the folder containing its source code, but not properly using pip

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download the package yourself from [here](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/40/a9837291310ee1ccc242ceb6ebfd9eb21539649f193a7c8c86ba15b98539/urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl) or find it yourself, and then try `pip install urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl` (replace the filename with the wheel you download). This way, you can reinstall `urllib3` without importing it first.

Comment: Same as in the original post.  urrlib3 is "reinstated" but 
   ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead